# Referring to an entity in another context - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to use `Any` method to achieve exists functionality in Entity Framework but when I refer to another entity in the current context, I get an error

> The name OrderNumber does not exists in current context

How can I fix this?

```
var ordResults = from ord in orders
                 select new Order
                        {
                            OrderId = ord.OrderId,
                            WarehouseId = ord.WarehouseId,
                            OrderNumber = ord.OrderNumber,
                            CustomerPoNumber = ord.CustomerPoNumber,
                            ShipToCode = ord.ShipToCode,
                            ShipToName = ord.ShipToName,
                            OrderDate = ord.OrderDate,
                            PromisedDate = ord.PromisedDate,
                            if (aadContext.TransactionLogs.Any(t => t.ControlNumber == **OrderNumber** && t.TransactionType == "670")) {"C"} else {"D"},
                            ord.Status,
                            ord.CustomerName,
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `ord.OrderNumber`?

Comment: How about adding a separate query for the transactions logs, After you get the orders and do the calculation. When your projecting and running this query you mostly have 2 quries running. I think so should check profiler for it.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this.

I still dont understand what  {"C"} else {"D"} if its condition you could add that like 
 
`t.somevalue=="C" || t.SomeValue=="E"`

```
var ordResults = from ord in orders
             let someValue = aadContext.TransactionLogs.Any(t => t.ControlNumber == ord.OrderNumber && t.TransactionType == "670")) 
             select new Order
                    {
                        OrderId = ord.OrderId,
                        WarehouseId = ord.WarehouseId,
                        OrderNumber = ord.OrderNumber,
                        CustomerPoNumber = ord.CustomerPoNumber,
                        ShipToCode = ord.ShipToCode,
                        ShipToName = ord.ShipToName,
                        OrderDate = ord.OrderDate,
                        PromisedDate = ord.PromisedDate,
                        DoYourValue = SomeValue
                        ord.Status,
                        ord.CustomerName,
                    }
```

Comment: I tried this an i am getting same error The name someValue does not exists in current context.